# Old Asian movie about foreseeing the future

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was this old Asian movie I watched as kid. I think it is made around 1960 - 1985 and I think it is a Japanese movie. The story follows below as I remember.

The main protagonist is a spy or solder who is called as Action King(Action Man?). While there was war the protagonist search for some weapon that will help his party with the war. He fell in love with another spy woman(or regular woman, not sure). There was multiple action scenes only I can remember few. There was a scene where the protagonist sneak past German Shepard dogs. Another is the protagonist use umbrella as weapon. After fight ends he opens the umbrella to shoot the wires of umbrella to the last enemy. The last one I remember is he and the spy woman jump off from a plane hugging and open a parachute. There was emotional argument between them about one of them should let go as the parachute is only enough for one. Both man and the woman is ready to sacrifice him/herself for the other. However they make it to the ground.

The woman is wounded (or dead) and the protagonist finds the weapon. It is about foreseeing the future. The protagonist sees the world future and sees the world is in chaos and destruction. He disappointed with what he just saw as his actions to make world a better place is not working.

The protagonist's son narrates the story of his father throughout the movie, on one occasion he comments the true love between the couple.

The main actor could be Stephen Chow or Sonny Chiba, not 100% sure.

Can you guide me to find this movie?

Comment: You're sure about the 1960-1985 ? Maybe some things you could remember about filming techniques or something that would allow to narrow down the time it was done ?

Comment: @sh5164 I vaguely remember it is a black and white movie. Sadly I can't confirm that 100%. I was very little(around 10 years old) when I watched that and I only watched it twice.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? 1985? Or later than that?

Comment: @LogicDictates Later. Probably around 2000-2005.